# PyQT CloseEvent function: Main window disappears

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I'm new to PyQT. I'm transferring one of my apps from tkinter to PyQT. What I want is the following scenario: When the user clicks the X button, the messagebox asking whether the user is sure about closing will appear while the main screen is still open. However, in my code, when the X button is clicked, the main screen disappears first and the message box arises. How can I solve this "order problem" -as I call? My code is below:

(In tkinter, this was easy with the code `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)` and an on_closing function containing `messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit Chit-Chat?")` command. However, I couldn't quite figure it out in PyQT.)

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

v_box = QVBoxLayout()

window = QWidget()
label = QLabel("Hello World")

v_box.addWidget(label)

def closeEvent():
    msg_box = QMessageBox()
choice = QMessageBox.question(msg_box, "Quit", "Do you want to quit chit chat?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
    if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
        print("The program was shut down.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        pass

app.aboutToQuit.connect(closeEvent)
window.setLayout(v_box)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        label = QLabel("Hello World")

        v_box = QVBoxLayout()
        v_box.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(v_box)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        choice = QMessageBox.question(
            self,  
            "Quit", 
            "Do you want to quit chit chat?", 
            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)

        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            print("The program was shut down.")
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    qt_app = Window()
    qt_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work when I convert into the functional paradigm. I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose if accept the event or not.

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    if self.popup_question():
        print("The program was shut down.")
        event.accept()
    else:
        print("not exiting")
        event.ignore()

def popup_question(self):
    """Generate a popup that requests if you want to do something or not."""
    msgbox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
    msgbox.setWindowTitle("Whatever title you want to add.")
    msgbox.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Warning)
    msgbox.setText("Do you want to quit chit chat?")
    botonyes = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Yes")
    msgbox.addButton(botonyes, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.YesRole)
    botonno = QtWidgets.QPushButton("No")
    msgbox.addButton(botonno, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoRole)
    msgbox.exec_()
    if msgbox.clickedButton() == botonno:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `functools` to override your window's widget `closeEvent` without creating a child class, then accept or cancel the close event using `event.accept()` or `event.ignore()`:

```
import functools
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel, QMessageBox


def closeEvent(self, event):
    choice = QMessageBox.question(self, "Quit", "Do you want to quit chit chat?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
    if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

v_box = QVBoxLayout()

window = QWidget()

window.closeEvent = functools.partial(closeEvent, window)

label = QLabel("Hello World")

v_box.addWidget(label)

window.setLayout(v_box)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```